# How to get json data only from parent class in hibernate one to many relationship in spring framework

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, rest

I am using spring framework and hibernate as an ORM tool.

My parent class is like:

```
@Entity

public class Category {
@Id
@GeneratedValue

@NotNull
private int cid;
private String cname;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@JoinColumn(name = "cid")
List<Ad> ads;
```

//getter and setter, constructor
}

And my child class is like:

```
@Entity
public class Ad {
private int adid;
private String adName;
//getter and setter, constructor
}
```

My category controller is :

```
@Controller
public class CategoryController {

@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;
Session session;
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "categories",method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Category> getAllCategory()throws SQLException{
    session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    return session.createCriteria(Category.class).list();
}
}
```

When i hit url localhost:8080/categories .I get json data like:

```
{"cid":"1",cname":"category","ads":[{"adid":"1","adName":"ad"}]}
```

Here I am getting datas of both parent and the related child table.But how can I get only datas of parent table.Here in this 
example, I need data like:

```
{"cid":"1",cname":"category"}
```

How can I do this

Answer (score 1):

I saw a nice article which describes exactly your problem.

[Json Exclude Property](http://www.davismol.net/2015/03/21/jackson-using-jsonignore-and-jsonproperty-annotations-to-exclude-a-property-only-from-json-deserialization/)

By configuring Entity using `@JsonIgnore` and `@JsonProperty` annotations you can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below

[Infinite Recursion with Jackson JSON and Hibernate JPA issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue)

Basically have to apply exclusion where you need to break the link